# Autosklearn prediction using Dask dataframe/ Autosklearn support for dask dataframes

Tags: dataframe, dask, automl, dask-dataframe

I have trained my Autosklearn classification model using pandas dataframe and trying to get predictions using dask dataframes from trained models.

I have tested with pandas dataframe and got predictions right. Now, i have to perform prediction task on dask dataframe for large datasets.

As i read all over documentaion of dask and Autosklearn, there is no support till now for the same.

If anyone can help, it will be very greatful.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

As of 2020-03-10 there is no support between Autosklearn and Dask dataframes.